# Wordpress: external Font doesn't show in Frontend

Tags: wordpress, css, font-face, webfonts

im trying to include an external Font in Wordpress with the follow code and it doesn't work:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Splatoon';
  src: url('http://paperyoshi.at/font/Splatoon/Splatoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('http://paperyoshi.at/font/Splatoon/Splatoon.woff') format('woff'),
       url('http://paperyoshi.at/font/Splatoon/Splatoon.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('http://paperyoshi.at/font/Splatoon/Splatoon.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('http://paperyoshi.at/font/Splatoon/Splatoon.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}

body {
    font-family: Splatoon;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `font-family: 'Splatoon' !important`?

Comment: @Gaspacchio I tried it yes but thank you very much

Comment: Using the quotes around your font name? Maybe (I know that is not really a good way to do it), it will work using `*` selector?

Comment: is it showing any error in console?

Comment: @Gaspacchio I tried it now without quotes and with * selector but it doens't work.

Comment: Now it worked, we reloaded the font to webspace. Thank you a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `!important`tag, put it behind css line for example 
`font-family: Arial !important;`

Answer (score 0):

If other tags like `p`, `li`, `h1` to `h6` etc. have specific font family settings, the font setting for `body` will hardly ever be effective. Check your theme stylesheet to see if there are font definitions for those tags, and if yes, create specific CSS rules which overwrite those.